# Webshop with different domains per brand

Tags: seo, multiple-domains

I'm creating a niche webshop which offers a limited number of products per brand/category which are somewhat similar to each other. However I have chosen to promote the products per brand on a different domain for extra search engine ranking. The layout will mostly be the same across domains. Customers will also switch over the domain during the process.

Maybe a little broad but the question is:
Which factors do I have to take account for regarding SEO? And then I mean for example: avoid duplicate content.

A few more specific questions:
Can I use the breadcrumb across the domains?
Does it affect SEO if the domains are pointing to the same host?.

Comment: What is the point of using two separate domains for the sales funnel of the same product? I must have missed this point. (The reasons you have for this are likely flawed/incorrect). Aside from anything else, this is awful UX (amongst many other factors).

Comment: @GeoffJackson-zigojacko: The products are not the same, they are completely different. The one thing what they have in common is how they are bought and used, what the customer gets differs per brand. Also the names and description corresponding to the product differs per brand. That's why I would like to have multiple domains. What do you mean by UX?

Comment: UX = User Experience (switching customers to a different domain partway through the sales funnel is not a great user experience). I still don't understand the point of what you're trying to achieve though @Tim. Why not just create one site on one domain with configurable products...? Thus keeping all your authority, branding on one site, with just the one site to market?

Answer (score 1):

In regards of SEO, you should just stick to the fundamentals as if you were making a single site. However, if I am understanding it correctly, you are trying to setup a multisite. Refer to this link for very important info regarding SEO for multisites and multiple TLDs websites

[click here](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2219759/Multiple-Domain-Choice-SEO-Considerations-of-Single-vs.-Multiple-Domains)

In regards of your breadcrumb. You can set up a breadcrumb with each domain very easily. However, one thing that you should remember is that a breadcrumb and a wayfinder are two different things. A breadcrumb is not a history. Its purpose is to show a user how to get to that page from home. So basically it can be done statically. Here's an example of the logic I would use.

HOME >> link 1 >> [Link2](http://google.com) >> link 3 >> YOU ARE HERE.

It takes some good mapping and site architecture to get it right. If the domains used are all hosted in the same server and you are using a multiple TLD site, you can use some dynamics to this code and post back to the server your location and have it return the name of your location or even from a database. But this is all unnecessary action on the server.

A wayfinder, is history based. This system posts back to the server the pages visited so that the visitor knows how he got there. In my opinion, this is pointless. You should only provide the visitor with a way back, a way out, and way to begin. That's it. You don't need to show a visitor all 300 pages he clicked to get to where he is now.